# Different Collisions

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have two collisions in my game that happen when the main characters hits an obstacle, game over appears and one where it touches the ground and nothing happens. This are the codes

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{

    if ([contact.bodyA.node.name isEqualToString:@"ground"] || [contact.bodyB.node.name isEqualToString:@"ground"]) {
        [hero land];
    } else {
        [self gameover];
    }
```

How can I add a different main character/hero collision where it doesn't lead me to game over but a whole different outcome (Like a different reaction for the main character)

Answer (score 0):

Try detecting contact for the other special cases:

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    BOOL isContactWithGround = ([contact.bodyA.node.name isEqualToString:@"ground"] || [contact.bodyB.node.name isEqualToString:@"ground"]);
    BOOL isContactWithHero = ([contact.bodyA.node.name isEqualToString:@"hero"] || [contact.bodyB.node.name isEqualToString:@"hero"]);
    BOOL isContactWithOtherThing = ([contact.bodyA.node.name isEqualToString:@"otherThing"] || [contact.bodyB.node.name isEqualToString:@"otherThing"]);


    if (isContactWithHero && isContactWithGround) {
        [hero land];
    } else if (isContactWithHero && isContactWithOtherThing) {
        [self doSomethingElse];
    else {
        [self gameover];
    }
}
```